# Replacing Headlight Assembly On Vehicle

Tags: ford, headlight, explorer

I am attempting to replace Headlight Assembly on 1996 Ford Explorer.  I have been able to get 2 of the 3 pins loosened so I can completely pull out the assembly.  The one I am stuck on is (using left side as an example) the pin on the bottom left that the long "rod" is attached to.  I have fat hands and can not maneuver them down to grip with my hand the circular "teeth" that need to be loosed.

What do I need to do to get that last clip removed so I can replace my headlight assembly?

Comment: A picture of the situation would help. There might be something nearby that can be loosened to allow your hands or tools to fit.

Comment: Some help here: http://www.explorerforum.com/forums/showthread.php?t=24257

Answer (score 1):

The only tool you need is a Philips head.  Use it to remove the blinker lights first  then remove the grill  (don't forget the 2screwsame behind the blinker lights ) don't turn any screws on the head lightstart just use your screwdriver and push on the black rubber  on the old headlights that's all that holds them in just pop them out and pop the new ones in